# Create masked square programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

I developed an iOS app and now working on the Android version.

I want to create the overlay view above the camera view (SurfaceView). The part which i cant replicate currently is the masked square overlay in the middle of the screen. I tried the `android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout` but it doesn't work as what i want.

For iOS version, I simply create 8 rectangular UIViews to form that shape. Then layout them by setting their CGRect.
But for Android, I know I can create them runtime using code. But the part I dont know is how to layout them.

Would like to have some advises, like which way should i go?(XML, or programmatically render).

Thanks a lot!

[image]]

Layout file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.nerfire.hk.flexibill.ScanMain">




    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/camera_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        />


    <!--<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout-->
        <!--android:orientation="vertical"-->
        <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
        <!--android:layout_height="match_parent">-->
        <!--<View-->
            <!--android:layout_width="match_parent"-->
            <!--app:layout_heightPercent="68%"-->
            <!--/>-->

    <!--</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>-->


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:text="Scan and Pay!"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: show your current layout file

Comment: Uploaded and updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right inside the `onCreateView` (using `Fragment`)

Here are the code, without refining the code, putting them in a for-loop

```
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);

    FrameLayout viewLayout = (FrameLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.scan_main_frame_layout);

    int overlayColor = Color.argb(127, 255, 255, 255);
    int lineWidth = 20;
    int lineLength = (int)(metrics.widthPixels*0.2);
    float originX = (float) (metrics.widthPixels*0.25);
    float endPointX = (float) (metrics.widthPixels*0.75);
    float screenCentreY = (float)(metrics.heightPixels*0.5);

    FrameLayout.LayoutParams horizontalLineFrame = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(lineLength, lineWidth);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams verticalLineFrame = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(lineWidth, lineLength-lineWidth);

    View view1 = new View(getContext());
    view1.setX(originX);
    view1.setY(screenCentreY-originX);
    view1.setBackgroundColor(overlayColor);
    view1.setLayoutParams(horizontalLineFrame);
    viewLayout.addView(view1);

    View view2 = new View(getContext());
    view2.setX(endPointX-lineLength);
    view2.setY(screenCentreY-originX);
    view2.setBackgroundColor(overlayColor);
    view2.setLayoutParams(horizontalLineFrame);
    viewLayout.addView(view2);

    View view3 = new View(getContext());
    view3.setX(originX);
    view3.setY(screenCentreY+originX-lineWidth);
    view3.setBackgroundColor(overlayColor);
    view3.setLayoutParams(horizontalLineFrame);
    viewLayout.addView(view3);

    View view4 = new View(getContext());
    view4.setX(endPointX-lineLength);
    view4.setY(screenCentreY+originX-lineWidth);
    view4.setBackgroundColor(overlayColor);
    view4.setLayoutParams(horizontalLineFrame);
    viewLayout.addView(view4);

    View view5 = new View(getContext());
    view5.setX(originX);
    view5.setY(screenCentreY-originX+lineWidth);
    view5.setBackgroundColor(overlayColor);
    view5.setLayoutParams(verticalLineFrame);
    viewLayout.addView(view5);

    View view6 = new View(getContext());
    view6.setX(endPointX-lineWidth);
    view6.setY(screenCentreY-originX+lineWidth);
    view6.setBackgroundColor(overlayColor);
    view6.setLayoutParams(verticalLineFrame);
    viewLayout.addView(view6);

    View view7 = new View(getContext());
    view7.setX(originX);
    view7.setY(screenCentreY+originX-lineLength);
    view7.setBackgroundColor(overlayColor);
    view7.setLayoutParams(verticalLineFrame);
    viewLayout.addView(view7);

    View view8 = new View(getContext());
    view8.setX(endPointX-lineWidth);
    view8.setY(screenCentreY+originX-lineLength);
    view8.setBackgroundColor(overlayColor);
    view8.setLayoutParams(verticalLineFrame);
    viewLayout.addView(view8);
```

Screenshot
[image]

ps: thanks for those who randomly left down votes without comment, without suggesting any solution or reading the question. Thanks mate:) nice android community.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.app.mynewproject.MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp" />

    <TextView
        android:text="SCAN AND PAY!"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

This is working as required.

Comment: I updated the question. The part which i cant replicate currently is the masked square overlay in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply put a `TextView` whose property set to `"android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` containg text Scan And Pay! in `RelativeLayout` which is also parent layout for `SurfaceView`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<SurfaceView
android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:text="SCAN AND PAY!"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or Use `FrameLayout` if no other views relative to other are present:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"   
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<SurfaceView
android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<TextView
android:textColor="@android:color/white"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom |center_horizontal"
android:text="SCAN AND PAY!"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I updated the question. The part which i cant replicate currently is the masked square overlay in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

`FrameLayout` is pretty basic container so if you need some more advanced features like positioning you should root `FrameLayout` with `RelativeLayout`, then in place of your (commented out) `android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout` element put ordinary `ImageView` showing your masking sqare. To center that `ImageView` ensure you got these set for it:

```
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
```

that should suffice.